# APR and Term to Principal Repayment Schedule Approximation

Tags: interest-rates, fixed-income, finance, reference-request

Is there any established "industry standard" to obtain an approximation for the expected principal repayment schedule for a given loan amount, term in months and APR with monthly payments ?

I realise the principal repayment will grow non-linearly, but since I'm dealing with terms less than 36 months and since I only need a rough approximation I'm hoping there is an accepted way to obtain a "growth factor" for a linear approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to require a similar answer to [an earlier post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/30960/7178) of mine, so notwithstanding my use of the same hammer for another nail, here goes.

*In short, the following just proves that the growth rate of the principal repayment is equal to the periodic interest rate.  With that the principal repayment schedule can be calculated quite simply.*

The balance of a loan follows this recurrence equation.

```
p[n + 1] = p[n] (1 + r) - d
```

where

```
p[n] is the balance of the loan in month n
r is the monthly interest rate
d is the regular monthly payment
```

This can be solved like so (using *Mathematica* in this instance).

```
RSolve[{p[n + 1] == p[n] (1 + r) - d, p[0] == s}, p[n], n]
```

where `s is the initial loan principal`

yielding `p[n_] := (d - d (1 + r)^n + r (1 + r)^n s)/r`

This notation expresses a formula for the balance in month n, which can be used in a function for the principal repayment `pr`, (that is, the regular repayment less the payment of interest on the previous month's balance).

```
pr[n_] := d - (p[n - 1] r)
```

Combining these expressions it follows that

$\text{pr}(n)=d (r+1)^{n-1}-r s (r+1)^{n-1}$

So for example, taking a £1000 loan over 3 years with 10% interest per month (rather high, but it's just an example), the monthly repayment `d` by standard formula is

```
s = 1000
r = 0.1
n = 36

d = (r (1+r)^n s)/(-1+(1+r)^n) = 103.34306381837332
```

Using these figures in a calculation of the principal repayment schedule:

```
s = 1000
r = 0.1
n = 36
d = 103.34306381837332

pr[1]
```

> 3.3430638183733237

```
pr[36]
```

> 93.94823983488523

```
ListPlot[Array[pr, 36]]
```

[image]

This plots the schedule of principal repayment over the 3 year term.

Consider the growth factors for two sample periods, from month 4 to 5 and from 35 to 36.

```
pr[5]/pr[4] - 1
```

> 0.1

```
pr[36]/pr[35] - 1
```

> 0.1

This is simply the monthly interest rate.

Put algebraically:

$\frac{\text{pr}(n+1)}{\text{pr}(n)}-1=\frac{d (r+1)^n-r s (r+1)^n}{d (r+1)^{n-1}-r s (r+1)^{n-1}}-1=r$

The growth rate of the principal repayment is equal to the periodic interest rate.

So the principal repayment schedule starts at `d - s r` and ends at `(d - s r)(1 + r)^(n - 1)`.

```
d - s r
```

> 3.3430638183733237

```
n = 36

(d - s r)(1 + r)^(n - 1)
```

> 93.94823983488523

as calculated earlier.

And of course the expression for the principal repayment simplifies as

$\text{pr}(n)=d (r+1)^{n-1}-r s (r+1)^{n-1}=(d-r s) (r+1)^{n-1}$